# Configuration files and Wix Toolset

Tags: xml, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer for an application, and it installs both an INI file, and an XML file (both of which are configuration files).

So having them as part of the install is not a great move, so now I've modified the install so that the files installed are DEFAULT files (.default), and I run a  element to copy to the real configuration file. The problem here, is that then the file is removed during an uninstall/upgrade.

So I have a custom action that copies the default files to 'real' config files, which means they will be left when uninstalling. This only works AFTER  (since before that, the file hasn't been laid down yet)

The problem is, there are wizard dialog pages and silent install parameters that the user could use to config the application during install. And when  or  run, the files haven't been copied yet!

The ideal fresh install sequence would be:

- default config INI/XML files are laid down
- 'real' config files are copied from originals
- INI values and XML modifications on UI/silent are made to 'real' config files

and then upgrade

- new default config INI/XML files are laid down
- INI values and XML modifications are made to 'real' config files

and uninstall

- application files and default files removed
- 'real' INI/XML config files left alone, suppressing INI/XML rollback

What should be the pattern for this?

I'm trying to make the scenario as simple to describe as possible. I feel like a design pattern exists/should exist for this.

What is the preferred pattern for allowing configuration parameters in an install, to be written to a file NOT (strictly) part of the install?

Comment: (just a quick response) If possible, I'd say to have any selections made by the user be written into the registry somewhere. Then, when the application is first launched it can read the registry and populate the user-data config files. This way the user's install-time choices persist for repair/modify/upgrade installs, and the installer doesn't have to worry about keeping up to date with the config file schemas from release to release. It's best to keep the installer out of the business of managing/persisting user data if at all possible...

Comment: @jbudreau is giving good advice - let the installer handle the default files, let the application itself perform user-level setup.  This becomes especially important when your application is installed by a second (admin) account on the machine.

Comment: So the installer should never ask any questions except "What directory?"

Comment: Using the word "never" can be tricky but generally, yes.  I really try to keep installers as simple and reliable as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad subject but in general my best practice approach is that the installer only lays down default values and always overwrites the files.  Then override files are used to provide customizations and the application loads in that order.  The installer doesn't know about these files so it never touches them.  The application has to be designed to do this and in some cases this isn't possible (web.config as an example).  In those cases you have to go through the extra work of loading the customizations you care about, overwriting the file and then reapplying them.

The heart of this problem is that INI and XML files are potentially infinite repositories of data and that the simple "overwrite or not overwrite"  servicing rules of MSI just don't work.  You eventually get into an unsolvable merge problem.   It's best to have 1 file the installer "owns" and always overwrites and one or more other files (layers) that the user or application owns that the installer doesn't know anything about and never modifies then let the application merge the data together to produce the final truth.

Look up my contact info if you'd like to have a more detailed discussion or explanations of why.  I'm always willing to discuss design issues without any obligation.

Comment: That does sound like a good ideal to work towards: The application handles it's own configuration, and has sensible defaults otherwise. But this is like the case of app/web.config. (Like a connection string which the program needs to even begin loading).  I guess an alternative is to make an entire configuration utility/wizard that runs when the install completes. That just doesn't feel any different than the installer asking a couple quick questions.

Comment: In that case it can get very tricky.  It generally takes custom action to retrieve values then overwrite the file and use another custom action to apply transforms to put the values back.  This way the installers and the applications source of truth are merged back together.  Very ugly and best to be avoided where possible.